# Mutation doesn't work GraphQL, Prisma, Yoga

Tags: graphql, prisma-graphql, plumatic-schema

How to add User in this example? I try to use mutation in all ways but doesn't work.

```js
type User {
  masterId: Int
  name: String
  surname: String
  address: Address 
}

type Address {
  street: String
  flat: Int
  city: String
  country: String
}
```

I try something like this:

```js
type Mutation {
  user(
    masterId: Int
    name: String
    surname: String
    address: Address
  ): User
}
```

and next

```js
mutation {
  user(
    masterId: 4,
      name: "Kevin",
      surname: "Key",
        address: {
        street: "Clark Street",
        flat: 19,
        city: "Brentwood",
        country: "United Kingdom"
      }
  ) 
}
```

I try different versions, but I really can not find a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in the playground after creating datamodel in prisma

```js
mutation {
  createUser(
    data: {
      name: "Kevin",
      surname: "Key"
      address: {
        create: {
          street: "Clark Street",
          flat: 19,
          city: "Brentwood",
          country: "United Kingdom"
        }
      }
    }
  ) {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

**Note**
You also use connect if address object is already created, for connect just pass the Address id(Primary Key/ObjectId)

Comment: Ok, thats work, but how move this to the schema.graphql (code app) and 
why you separated "name"?

Comment: You will get tutorial here:  https://www.prisma.io/tutorials/build-a-graphql-server-from-scratch-ct01/